# Flutter Cupertino context menu that is not full screen overlay and works with onTap

Tags: flutter

Is there a Flutter Cupertino context menu that is not full screen overlay and works with onTap?

I have seen CupertinoContextMenu but that is not quite right as it requires onPressed with no way to use onTap

Image of what I am after below:

[image]